# Extract elements from a given stl container with given predicate to another container

Tags: c++, stl

What is the best way to extract and move elements that meet certain criteria from a STL container to another STL container (e.g., `vector`). For example:

```
std::vector<int> original {1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 34, 9, 7, 3}

// For example, I only need event numbers
auto criteria = [](const int a) -> bool { return a%2 == 0? }

std::vector<int> newvec = ...;
```

So, what I want after the operation is

```
original = {1, 7, 9, 9, 7, 3}
newvec = {2, 6, 34}
```

An elegant solution will be appreciated.

Comment: So the goal is to **copy** something **if** it meets a specified criterion? Read about `std::copy_if`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with customized erase/remove predicate, that would add the removed elements to `newvec`:

```
original.erase(std::remove_if(original.begin(), original.end(), [&](int n){
    bool match = criteria(n);
    if(match){
        newvec.push_back(n);
    }
    return match;
}));
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uVKZ9TCbkdKD4ThJ)

You might want to consider throwing [`vector<T>::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) into the mix if you know the approximate number of elements meeting your criteria.

Comment: I guess the OP doesn't want to _copy if_, he wants to _move if_.

Comment: @skypjack yeah. It seems I missed the memo that one should be capable of comprehending the questions before answering them.

Comment: A clever use of the idiom indeed. Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such algorithm in STL but it is short to write:

```
template <typename FIterator, typename OIterator, typename Pred>
FIterator splice_if( FIterator first, FIterator last, OIterator out, Pred p )
{
   FIterator result = first;
   for ( ; first != last; ++first ) {
       if ( p( *first ) ) {
           *result++ = *first;
       } else {
         *out++ = *first;
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For objects of type `int` there is no great sense to use move iterators however in general case you can use move iterators.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows an approach to the task

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> original {1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 34, 9, 7, 3};

    auto odd_value = []( int x ) { return x & 1; };

    auto n = std::count_if( original.begin(), original.end(), odd_value );

    std::vector<int> odd;
    odd.reserve( n );
    std::vector<int> even;
    even.reserve( original.size() - n );

    std::partition_copy( std::make_move_iterator( original.begin() ), 
                         std::make_move_iterator( original.end() ),
                         std::back_inserter( odd ),
                         std::back_inserter( even ),
                         odd_value );

    original = odd;

    for ( int x : original ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : even ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 7 9 9 7 3 
2 6 34
```